# POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 502

Tags: azure, .net-core, botframework, azure-keyvault

I've developed a chatbot using `botframework` and it just works fine and deployed in azure also fine.

Then I added `KeyVault` service and published again but this time I'm getting 502 error and in `appInsights` this log:

```
   Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotException:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   Inner exception System.Exception handled at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

When I've removed(commented part) the code for implementing the KeyVault service, it worked again:

```
 public static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                    {
                       // var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                       // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                       // {
                       //     var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                       //     var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new  VaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                       //    builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                       //  }
                    }
                ).UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

        private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => "https://XXX.vault.azure.net/";
```

These are the steps and the code from [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service), which I've implemented

Answer (score 0):

This is ***typically*** because the bot times out. The bot needs to respond within 15 seconds to the direct line channel.  You can do further debugging/logging/testing to see if this is the scenario in this case. You can also use Ngrok to debug locally to see if needed.

Comment: with ngrok I'm getting always unautherized! I'm testing in Teams and Webchat

Comment: so, it works fine with ngrok :/ I'm getting the 502 when publish

Comment: Do you have the appid/password configured just in the appsettings.json, or do you have it setup in the app services configuration as well? I would try and configure it in both, just to ensure that it is configured everywhere (and somewhat a troubleshooting step).

Comment: Now, Publish is succeeded, but api/messages returns bad gateway..
AppId is identic in both app service and the web app bot.. password is configured only in app service, where I think, it is the one place to configure :)
It is anyways not Timeout, because I'm getting the error in 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you create a new password (client secret, under `Certificates & secrets`) for your app (go [here](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade)) and replace the password in the configuration.